# Java Wiremock random string test failure

Tags: java, json, wiremock

I'm generating some JSON which i'm using Wiremock to test. However, I now need to add a randomly generated string to the JSON which obviously changes each time my test is run. This causes the assertion to fail. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this issue?

Json:

```
"data": {
    "case": {
      "user": {
        "name": {
          "title": "Mr",
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        "address": { }
      }
    },
    "subscriptions": {
      "userSubscription": {
        "randomNumber": "{{I am a random string so fail}}",
        "email": null,
        "mobile": null
      },
      "supporterSubscription" : null
   }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void should_handle_callback()
    throws Exception {

    submitStub();

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>("string");

    // fails
    ResponseEntity<CallbackResponse> result =
        this.restTemplate.postForEntity(baseUrl, request, CallbackResponse.class);
}

private static String loadJson(String fileName) throws IOException {
    URL url = getResource(fileName);
    return Resources.toString(url, Charsets.toCharset("UTF-8"));
}

private void submitStub() throws Exception {

    ccdServer.stubFor(post(concat(SUBMIT_EVENT_URL))
            .withHeader(AUTHORIZATION, equalTo(USER_AUTH_TOKEN))
            .withHeader(SERVICE_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, equalTo(SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN))
            .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, equalTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .withRequestBody(equalToJson(createCaseRequest))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(loadJson("testjson.json"))));
}
```

Comment: `randomNumber` generates using your code? could you mock it, to generate pseudo-random string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any 'out of the box' ways to assert against wildcards inside the body of the request. I have encountered a similar issue in the past and have used the criteria queries in the past which work reasonably well.

http://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/

Have a look at the 'Criteria Queries' section of that page which shows and example of how to query the request log directly.

The code should look something similar to this:

```
List<LoggedRequest> requests = findAll(postRequestedFor(urlMatching("/api/.*")));
```

After you've got back this list of requests you can loop over the results to find if one of LoggedRequest bodies contains the json you're looking for.

A good library for checking whether a JSON matches with wildcards is JSON-Unit which allows you to populate fields which are automatically generated with "${json-unit.ignore}".

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit

Your assertion might look something like this:

```
assertThatJson(requests.get(0).getBodyAsString())
  .isEqualTo("{\"id\":\"${json-unit.ignore}\",\"name\":\"bob\"}");
```